# IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP fails when set both on interface and its subinterface; is that expected?

Tags: sockets, networking, multicast

I'm debugging a [3rd-party network application](https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-transport/src/c14cdb42c65900f284e9831c0f2f78033bfa2615/include/ignition/transport/Discovery.hh#Discovery.hh-1036) and trying to figure out why it reports errors when calling `setsockopt` with `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` to set up a multicast group. The application is in C++, but I've written an MWE in python that replicates the same syscalls:

```
import socket
import struct

ETH0_IP = "192.168.88.85"
ETH0_1_IP = "192.168.88.254"

MULTICAST_IP = "224.0.0.7"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
ip = socket.inet_aton(ETH0_IP)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ip)
group = struct.pack("4s4s", socket.inet_aton(MULTICAST_IP), ip)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, group)
# s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
# s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
ip2 = socket.inet_aton(ETH0_1_IP)
s2.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ip2)
group2 = struct.pack("4s4s", socket.inet_aton(MULTICAST_IP), ip2)

# the second group is added to the first socket so that we can only bind to one socket and read data from it
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, group2)
```

At the second `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` call I get error `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

I found out this only happens when `ETH0_1_IP` is a subinterface of `ETH_0_IP`. And I'm not sure if this is expected. If it is, is there a way to actually detect this situation and discard subinterfaces of already bound interfaces? Further, would my multicast socket receive data sent to the subinterface if registration for it fails with the above error?

For the sake of completeness:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.88.254
    netmask 255.255.240.0
```

Comment: This is a receiver code or a sender code?

Comment: Not sure, the app has both server and client parts, but this error message is shown when starting up the server, so I assume it should be connected with the receiver part.

Comment: That means it a sender/server. I am no expert in this area, but I think your usage of socket may be wrong. I would look at some work from github in this case like https://github.com/hymanc/purpleproject1/blob/e77b9bf5b9fde453fc41d9a80b7cb1886d7ec846/model/rxMcast.py, https://github.com/bhuztez/ercraft/blob/0d52c0ddd9a9e8c96edfc6eb300068e15dce8c74/share/discover.py, https://github.com/adamzfc/python_demo/blob/88c2d15cf17e636b95f3070bc9fd81920e8ab4b4/multicast_send.py and find out what is being done wrongly. One can usually bind to a sub interface as well as main interface

Comment: I think you can improve your python sample and make it clearer removing commented lines and removing the second socket `s2` that is not used.

Comment: As I understand it, all you've done is create an alias to the existing physical adaptor.  Since this is just an obsolete feature of Linux (to configure multiple IP addresses om one interface), my guess is that under the covers, it knows that this is the same interface and so is rejecting the second attempt to use the same interface.

Comment: @mpromonet Read the question again, please. `s2` is used.

Comment: @PeterBrittain That's my guess, too, but I'm looking for an answer that's more than just guesswork...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is tracking your alias interface as the same interface and so rejecting the attempt to re-use the interface.

In a bit more detail, I have run your code successfully on CentOS 7 using two separate physical interfaces with no changes.  If I then change the code to use an alias on the same physical address, it fails with the same error that you see.

Digging a little further, I see that if I dump the interface indeces (using SIOCGIFINDEX) for the physical adaptor and the alias, they do indeed have the same index.

If you want to use Python to check this for yourself, have a quick look at https://gist.github.com/firaxis/0e538c8e5f81eaa55748acc5e679a36e for some code (missing imports of ctypes and socket) and then try something like this:

```
print(Interface(name="eth0").index)
print(Interface(name="eth0:1").index)
```

Comment: Thanks, so it seems the code should check the interface numbers and make sure the call is only executed once for each interface number.